# AutoIT script - Compare Paint's Rotated Image with GDI's rotated image

Tags: image, rotation, automation, autoit

I have an image and rotate it with both MS Paint and GDI. I want to show that the rotated image from both methods are the same.

Here is the code I have to rotate image with GDI

```
#include <GDIPlus.au3>

_GDIPlus_Startup()

$hImage1 = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\Picture.gif")
$hGraphic1 = _GDIPlus_ImageGetGraphicsContext($hImage1)
$hImage2 = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromGraphics(_GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($hImage1), _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($hImage1), $hGraphic1)
$hGraphic2 = _GDIPlus_ImageGetGraphicsContext($hImage2)

$matrix = _GDIPlus_MatrixCreate()
_GDIPlus_MatrixRotate($matrix,90)
_GDIPlus_GraphicsSetTransform($hGraphic2, $matrix)
_GDIPlus_GraphicsDrawImage($hGraphic2, $hImage1, 0, -590)

_GDIPlus_ImageSaveToFile($hImage2, @ScriptDir & "\out.gif")

_GDIPlus_MatrixDispose($matrix)
_GDIPlus_GraphicsDispose($hGraphic1)
_GDIPlus_GraphicsDispose($hGraphic2)
_GDIPlus_ImageDispose($hImage1)
_GDIPlus_ImageDispose($hImage2)

 _GDIPlus_ShutDown ()
```

Then I used this code to compare 2 images:

```
$bm1 = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\Picture1.gif")
$bm2 = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\out.gif")

if ComparePicture($bm1, $bm2) == True Then
   MsgBox(0, "Test result", "Same image!")
Else
   MsgBox(0, "Test result", "Different image!")
EndIf

_GDIPlus_ImageDispose($bm1)
_GDIPlus_ImageDispose($bm2)
_GDIPlus_Shutdown()

Func ComparePicture($bm1, $bm2)

$Bm1W = _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($bm1)
$Bm1H = _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($bm1)
$BitmapData1 = _GDIPlus_BitmapLockBits($bm1, 0, 0, $Bm1W, $Bm1H, $GDIP_ILMREAD, $GDIP_PXF08INDEXED )
$Stride = DllStructGetData($BitmapData1, "Stride")
$Scan0 = DllStructGetData($BitmapData1, "Scan0")

$ptr1 = $Scan0
$size1 = ($Bm1H - 1) * $Stride + ($Bm1W - 1) * 4


$Bm2W = _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($bm2)
$Bm2H = _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($bm2)
$BitmapData2 = _GDIPlus_BitmapLockBits($bm2, 0, 0, $Bm2W, $Bm2H, $GDIP_ILMREAD, $GDIP_PXF08INDEXED)
$Stride = DllStructGetData($BitmapData2, "Stride")
$Scan0 = DllStructGetData($BitmapData2, "Scan0")

$ptr2 = $Scan0
$size2 = ($Bm2H - 1) * $Stride + ($Bm2W - 1) * 4

$smallest = $size1
If $size2 < $smallest Then $smallest = $size2
$call = DllCall("msvcrt.dll", "int:cdecl", "memcmp", "ptr", $ptr1, "ptr", $ptr2, "int", $smallest)



_GDIPlus_BitmapUnlockBits($bm1, $BitmapData1)
_GDIPlus_BitmapUnlockBits($bm2, $BitmapData2)

Return ($call[0]=0)
EndFunc
```

I tried changing the file type, color depth, etc. but I could not get the code to show that they are the same. When I do not rotate the picture i.e

```
_GDIPlus_MatrixRotate($matrix,0)
```

then it recognize the same image. When I rotate right 90, it doesn't. Does anyone knows what might be going on?

Thanks

---

For reference, this question has also been asked on the AutoIt forums [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/160798-compare-paints-rotated-image-with-gdis-rotated-image).

Comment: When rotating in AutoIt, you are making both images the same dimensions, don't you want width and height to be swapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$GDIP_PXF08INDEXED` is modifying the images differently. Try it without setting it and it should work.

Furthermore, you can use this code to flip the image:

```
$hImage1 = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\Picture1.gif")
_GDIPlus_ImageRotateFlip($hImage1, 1) ;90°

_GDIPlus_ImageSaveToFile($hImage1, @ScriptDir & "\out.gif")

_GDIPlus_ImageDispose($hImage1)
```

Br,

UEZ